# Document Library level search is giving error - Error code: -2147467259 in Modern SharePoint (Team Site)

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, document-set, modern-team-site, modern-document-library

When I am trying to search using metadata in the document library getting the below error

[image: Error Code - 2147467259]

However, whenever I am searching on the OOTB Modern SPO search page, it's giving me the result using same metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue. Actually, I created library views using a script as part of site provision, and just editing the views manually solved the issue in my case.

> - Open view
> - Edit view (not made any changes in view)
> - Save view

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue.

[image]

**The error is in response to the View setting of list. You unknowingly was attempting to have many Lookup columns in a single View.**

[image]

SharePoint Online limits the number of lookup column. Lists created prior to the June 2013 CU update are capped at 8 lookup columns, while those afterward are allowed 12.

Although the official said can have 12 Lookup fields under a single View. But in my test environment, **the number of Lookup fields cannot exceed 10**, otherwise an error will occur.

Once I edited the view to only contain a few Lookup columns in the default, the problem stopped.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. I am using only 6 lookup columns in my view.

Comment: Hi, Virendra Kumar. Thanks for your reply. Glad to hear that your problem has been resolved. You can mark your Answer. This can help users who encounter this problem to reference.

Finally, thank you for sharing. Have a nice day!